# can't create subtask

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, task-list

I can't create a new sub task in all tasks view under the parent task.

It told me that

> We can't modify hierarchy on view that is sorted

The view doesn't have sort or group or filter, the same error happened if I tried to use move up / down

Any thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you can not have a sort set for that view. Update your sort and choose **None**. Other views you can use the sort options as needed but the main view in a task list needs to be unsorted to retain the relationship between parent / child tasks. Remember even if you don't have sort for the view you can still use the column headers to manually sort or filter the items.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just expand on Chris's answer - he's right.

Some functions on certain lists don’t work if your default view is grouped, sorted or filtered. Case in point: in the Tasks web part, if you try to indent tasks in the filtered view (i.e. My Tasks) – you will get the following error message: We can’t modify hierarchy on a view that is sorted/filtered/grouped.

As a result,  don’t change that default view in SharePoint. If you decide to view information differently, you should create your own custom views.

https://sharepointmaven.com/dont-change-default-view-sharepoint/